# Maven build passes with test failures in the site phase

Tags: maven, build, maven-2, maven-surefire-plugin

Ive included the surefire-report plugin to generate html reports.
When I run "mvn site", it runs my tests and generates the reports but the build passes even if there are test failures.

On the other hand, if I run "mvn install site", the build fails at the test failure and does not even do the site phase. I tried adding -fae but does not help. How can i prevent this?

Ideally I would like it to run through all tests in all my modules, run site, generate the reports and then fail the build.

Note, -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false already but no use. Also, if i remove the surefire-report plugin, everything is fine.

On a side note, any good alternatives to surefire-report plugin to generate html junit test reports?